# GULP 4 Ошибка:"AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified"

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    minCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('minCSS',function(){
    gulp.src('app/css/main.css')
    .pipe(minCSS())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('minJS', function () {
    gulp.src('app/js/main.js')
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('serve', ['minCSS', 'minJS'], function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "app/"
    });

    gulp.watch("app/css/*.css", ['minCSS']);
    gulp.watch("app/js/*.js", ['minJS']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Здесь подключаю browserSync , после прописываю gulp и выдаёт ошибку AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified. Gulp 4 версии

Answer (score 0):

Если еще актуально...

В gulp4 поменяли синтаксис из-за синхронности и асинхронности, чтобы меньше было ошибок. 
Теперь надо разделять что запускать синхронно через  gulp.series() или асинхронно gulp.parallel().

По вашему коду, надо заменить

gulp.task('serve', ['minCSS', 'minJS']

на

```js
gulp.task('serve', gulp.parallel('minCSS', 'minJS'), function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "app/"
    });

    gulp.watch("app/css/*.css", gulp.parallel('minCSS'));
    gulp.watch("app/js/*.js", gulp.parallel('minJS'));
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'));
```

Как-то так... Если я что-то напутал, попробуйте поменять parallel на series.